# Can I replace std::async with c++20 coroutines?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, c++20, c++-coroutine

I am developing a game.

In It, I have a gameloop function. This gameloop function is used during map loading.
In it's update method it queries a state object which contains the map loading progress and a few other things.

The map loading itself is currently implemented via `std::async`:

```
std::atomic<int8_t> progress = 0;
auto level_future = std::async(std::launch::async | std::launch::deferred, load_level_data, std::ref(progress), level, game_state);
```

the function `load_level_data` occasionally updates `progress` during the loading/decoding process.

Now I wondered if I could replace `std::async` with a coroutine?

As far as I understood coroutines, I can just add `co_yield` statements through the function with the progress value and use it in my gameloop in a while loop until progress has the desired value?

Pseudocode:

```
<return type ?> load_level_data(level_file) {
    read_file_into_buffer();
    progress = 5;
    co_yield progress;
    decode_file();
    progress = 10;
    co_yield progress;
    fill_runtime_data();
    progress = 70;
    co_yield progress;
    finish_loading();
    progress= 100;
    co_yield progress;

    ??? return decoded level file here???
}
```

```
int progress = 0;


while(progress != 100)
{
    progress = yield load_level_data("foo");
}
level = load_level_data("foo") // get decoded level?
```

Comment: coroutine and async are different because async uses thread in it. In other words, coroutine and thread are different. Maybe your function can use any of them to do its job. But their performance may be different. What you need to do is to do your own benchmark...

Comment: what do threads have to do with the question?
I can also just call `load_level_data` without `std::async`. It will just block until it's done.
My consideration was that coroutines may help getting rid of the `std::async` for readability.

Comment: You probably could use coroutine or async to do your loading, but if your coroutine `co_yield` not "enough", you game might "freeze".

Comment: "*what do threads have to do with the question?*" - they have to do with the `std::async` part.

Comment: @Fureeish I understand that `std::async` is likely to spawn a thread or uses a threadpool. My question is not about threads *per se*, but if i can replace std::async with a coroutine. My concern is not performance or the like, but easy-to-understand- client code. At the moment, I am using an atomic integer to synchronize my gameloop with the map loading .
A coroutine would make things more readable (Gameloop would call coroutine in a loop)

Comment: @Raildex: Here's the question: *why* did you use `async` for level loading? If it is because you wanted level loading to not block the main thread, then for your coroutine version to be equivalent, it would *also* have to not block the main thread. So, what problem did you solve by using `async` in the first place?

Comment: @NicolBolas I am displaying a Loading screen with a percentage bar that is animated.

Comment: Do you need to support some kind of GUI responsiveness during the loading? If not, everything can be done serially and there would be no need to any kind of asynchronicity.

Comment: @Fureeish A coroutine would be the "cleanest", see my pseudocode.
I can just call the coroutine in a loop until the loading is finished.
The only thing I fail to see is how to cleanly transfer the decoded level to the caller of the routine.

Comment: You didn't answer my question.

Comment: @Fureeish The only responsiveness I need is an occasional update of the loading screen to update the loading bar

Comment: So why not ditch asynchronicity completely? Just load the level in a blocking fashion and everywhere where you have your proposed `co_yield progress`, just `update()` the progress bar with said `progress`.